# Laravel localization

Tags: php, laravel, localization

Here is what confuses me. I have a config file in app/config named "myconfig.php" :

```
<?php

return array (
'default_language' => 'en',
);
```

In app/config/app.php I`m trying to set the default language from my config file like this:

```
'locale' => Config::get('myconfig.default_language')
```

and I got this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Class 'Config' not found
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Why not define the language in app.php right away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like app.php is the initial config file and at the time it is called, none of the other configs is called and recognized.